# Insufficient permissions for your Apple ID Fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm new to auto deployment on iOS and I'm following the [guide from the web](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/). On the guide, I selected #2 (Automate beta distribution to TestFlight) and then it asked me for my user id and password from apple, after I login successfully, it says:

```
Requesting session...
[15:50:29]: --------------------
[15:50:29]: fastlane init failed
[15:50:29]: --------------------
[15:50:29]: ["Insufficient permissions for your Apple ID:", "User email@email.com doesn't have enough permission for the following action: user_details_data"]
```

I didn't create this project, my friend did, his name is on the builder identifier, and we are both working on it, this is how my signing capabilities look like:

[image]

Could that be why it gave me the error? I'm able to compile and run the app.

Also is there a tutorial that goes in detail, maybe a video about beta automation for iOS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set up apple store connect account for Testflight (probably your user not in members for the project)

Comment: Is Testflight free or do I have to purchase the developer license?

Comment: If you joined Apple Developer Program (which costs 100$ a year) than you should have access to appstoreconnect, in any case, you need to be a member of Apple Developer Program for the app

Comment: oh.. would you recommend me another way to do pipelining on ios without the developer program?

Comment: if your friend has joined Apple Developer Program you can ask him to host your app and add you as a member to an app but without joining program it won't work

Comment: he doesn’t have one either, we are students doing the senior project and the product owner doesn’t want to pay for the apple dev prog

Comment: Is there a way to build a pipeline CI/DD without the apple developer id?